# Custom button content alignment

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I'm trying to create custom buttons in `xaml`. It's going great but i have some weird problems with the alignment of the content.

If i place a custom button in the `"root grid"`, the whole button is clickable, and the content (text of the button) is properly center-aligned.

However if i place my custom buttons in this way:

- Border

  - StackPanel

    - MyButtons
    - MyButtons
    - Etc...

Then, my button's - content is also properly centered, but only clickable on the content's text. Not the whole button...

If i set my content-alignment to stretch, it is clickable, but the text isn't center.

Here's my xaml: How can i make the whole button clickable in the above setup?

**ControlTemplate:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ollema">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border Name="border" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                </ContentPresenter>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**XAML in my MainWindow:**

```
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Width="200" Background="#FF00641E" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Is this the `ControlTemplate` for the `Button` itself? if so switch the `ContentControl` inside it to `ContentPresenter`. and set the `Style` to have a default `Setter` for `Background` to be `Transparent` and also add `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` to your `Grid`.

Comment: @Viv Yes, it's the `ControlTemplate` itself. I tried what you proposed but it's giving me the same result. I think it has something to do with that my `buttons` are contained in a `stackpanel` and my stackpanel in a `border`. I'll play around a bit more..

Comment: well can you add your full xaml code then please. I cannot reproduce this with just the code you've posted. Style, StackPanel, everything pretty much in xaml relating to this.

Comment: @Viv Thank you, i edited my post. Note that i'm quite newbie to xaml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DeMama Set your `Background` in the `ToggleButton`'s to `Transparent` instead of `x:Null`

Something like

```
<Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0" Width="200" Background="#FF00641E" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"/>
            <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource ollema}" Content="ToggleButton" Height="57" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFE8E8E8" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Just tried this and the click event is invoked fine even if outside the `ContentPresenter`

Comment: Great it works like a charm ! Thanks man, didn't knew it would be this easy :)

Comment: @DeMama Your welcome. Most problems always have simple solutions. Just about finding em :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put

```
VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

for both the stackpanel and the contentPresenter

Comment: Already tried that, but then my `button content` is on the `Top-left` position, i need it to be in center..

Comment: add some margin to your ContentPresenter or some padding to your stackpanel